# Typesafe way to use Mockk and extension functions

Tags: kotlin, mocking, mockk

It seems that [a recommended way to mock extensions with Mockk](https://blog.kotlin-academy.com/mocking-is-not-rocket-science-mockk-advanced-features-42277e5983b5) is to define a `@file:JvmName` and refer to it with `mockkStatic("<jvm-name>")`, which is not type safe: In case of refactoring (e.g. rename or package change), the tests might break inadvertently. Is there a more type safe manner to mock extension functions?

Answer (score 2):

In addition to `mockkStatic("<jvm-name>")` [it is also possible](https://mockk.io/#extension-functions) to define use `mockkStatic(Type::extension)`. While it can imply more boilerplate for several extensions, it will be more robust and will allow to safely refactor your code.